# iOS Code Signing Error

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I'm trying to install and run a basic iOS application on my iPhone. The error I am getting when I try to build and install is:

```
CodeSign /Users/jacob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newProject-bttbyexujwyetreshrllqrqmpouw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/newProject.app
cd /Users/jacob/code/iphone/newProject
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin"
setenv _CODESIGN_ALLOCATE_ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Developer: Jacob LYLES (P4AAK856G5)" --resource-rules=/Users/jacob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newProject-bttbyexujwyetreshrllqrqmpouw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/newProject.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /Users/jacob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newProject-bttbyexujwyetreshrllqrqmpouw/Build/Intermediates/newProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/newProject.build/newProject.xcent /Users/jacob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newProject-bttbyexujwyetreshrllqrqmpouw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/newProject.app

/Users/jacob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newProject-bttbyexujwyetreshrllqrqmpouw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/newProject.app: The operation was cancelled by the user.
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I've deleted and redownloaded all my provisioning profiles and certificates and whatnot a million times. Any help is much appreciated. I can provide more information as needed. I am using iOS 4.3 SDK on XCode 4.0.

edit: Please keep in mind that the project compiles, installs, and runs perfectly on the simulator where no code signing is needed.

Comment: i think the EXIT CODE error will occur only when you forget to add some of the contents od your project.. may be you might have forgot to add some key files.. please check your app once again...

Comment: I don't think this is the case. Can you give me some specifics of which files you think I could be missing? Keep in mind that the app works perfectly on the simulator.

Comment: code signing error had nothing to do with simulator... are u adding anything to ur code through absolute path???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please check your bundle identifier in info.plist, and if it is also correct restart both  your device and machine and then made build and also select proper version of SDK, It may work.

Comment: Restarting my machine and logging in again to the provisioning profile did it. So frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

I had been having this problem each time I change to a new computer, this is my solution:

1. Go to your keychain Access, under **Login** | **Certificates** and delete those certificates.
2. Login on developer.apple.com
3. Go to Provisioning Portal.
4. Go to Certificates and REVOKE your profile.
5. Create a new one (using the guide on site).
6. Download and Open your new Certificate.
7. Download and Install your Provisioning Profile.
8. Go to Xcode, Clean and Build.
9. Assign your certificates to the code sign in sections again...

And voila! That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your deployment target? Alot of people confuse the term Base SDK  strangely represents the highest version of OS your app will run on, therefor, the lower it is, the greater the chances of compatibility are.

Comment: I cranked my deployment target down to a lower version with no noticeable effect on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use your provisioning profile for build. set it in info of project as well as in target (get info + build tab + code signing identity)and also set bundle identifier in yourApp-Info.pList.

Answer (score 0):

Had some rather incomprehensible problems with CodeSign in Xcode 4 today. The problem started when I installed Xcode 4.2 beta to try and resolve some iOS 5.0 issues with my apps. I ended up uninstalling it and going back to Xcode 4.1 and thats when my problems started. I got the following error when building my apps:

> ... object file format invalid or unsuitable
>   Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

I tried everything, re-downloading certificates, provisioning profiles, code signing build settings, the lot. Nothing seemed to help. A lot of googling revealed no definitive answer.

In the end it turned out to be something quite obscure. There is supposed to be a symlink `/usr/bin/codesign_allocate`. It must have been deleted during an uninstall. So I ran the following to recreate it:

```
sudo ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate /usr/bin
```

Xcode, clean and build and everything was fine.

Hope this information proves useful and saves you time.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that causes this error is changing your login keychain password. Maybe you work at a place that forces you to change your password every so often. Next time you do so, you could possibly start getting this error. Simply logging out then back in will fix it.